# BeautifulSoup path optimization

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

What will be better for optimization using BeautifulSoup to select path.

Better is using full path, start from body, like:
`body section div .uniqueClass .element a`
or
`.uniqueClass .element a`?

Comment: Care to elaborate clearly on what you're asking?

Answer (score 0):

Of course `.uniqueClass .element a` is better and faster because it will skip loop through unnecessary element `section` and `div`.